# Shortening time to complete regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find from an external file a user-inputted expression and the 5 words (as flexible as possible) around it. However, the regex to find 5 words is taking far too long to complete

```
'(?:(.+)?\w+(.+)? ){5}'
```

So to create the expression  I'm using:

```
exp='(?:(.+)?\w+(.+)? ){5}'
find=input("What would you like to find?")
exp+=find
exp+='(?:(.+)?\w+(.+)? ){5}'
```

I know the problem isn't with the actual code because using an expression like `.20{}` works fine.

Comment: How long is your string ?

Comment: @user312016 what I'm searching for is usually just a single word

Comment: To match 5 words, use `(\b\w+\b){5}` ?

Answer (score 1):

it would be much faster to find the line that has the word in it first then get the words afterwards once you've found the line.

Currently you're having to compare a much longer string due to the 5 word requirement.

So just find the word, then parse the surrounding elements (even use the regex here if you need to).

Comment: Ok, how would I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm a bit of a beginner with this

Comment: @E.Asquith -  `if word in line`? I assume you're working through a file line by line rather than using one massive bulk string?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regex, you should use normal string operations.

```
wordPos = fileContent.find(userInput)
wordAmount = 5
extractionBegin = wordPos
for i in range(wordAmount + 1):
    extractionBegin = fileContent.rfind(' ', extractionBegin)
extractionEnd = wordPos
for i in range(wordAmount + 1):
    extractionEnd = fileContent.find(' ', extractionEnd)
print fileContent[extractionBegin:extractionEnd]
```